# How to redirect only the root path in nginx?

Tags: redirect, nginx

I only want to redirect the root path from domain A to domain B. For example, if user type in https://www.a.com/ or https://www.a.com or http://a.com all redirect to https://www.b.com/, but if user type in https://www.a.com/something/ then it keep there without redirect.

I tried the following:

```
location / {
    return 301 https://www.b.com/;
}
```

but it redirect all to www.b.com even user type in https://www.a.com/something/.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I got it.

```
location ~ ^/$ {
    return 301 https://www.b.com/;
}
```

Comment: See other answer, no need for regex.

Answer (score 57):

I found another similar solution, I think it is more concise:

```
location = / {
    return 301 http://www.b.com/;
}
```

[Link to source](https://serverfault.com/a/491066/434003)

Comment: = / form appears more intuitive and perhaps has become canonical.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it is cleaner and more lightweight than the regex.